# getting all attributes of an object python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, attributes

I read all questions and answers about this but none seems to help , using var from one of the answers was close but i need to use the same function with different objects. What should i change in the function so i don't have to make multiple functions for each object, i mean say i have another objects Human , Plants do i have to make a function for each one just changing the animal syntax:

```
class Animal(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.legs = 2
          self.name = 'Dog'
          self.color= 'Spotted'
          self.smell= 'Alot'
          self.age  = 10
          self.kids = 0

def get_info(self) :
    if __name__ == '__main__':
       animal = Animal()
       temp = vars(animal)
       for item in temp:
           print(item , ' : ' , temp[item])
```

Comment: So pass in the other objects to `vars()`? The loop is just printing out the variables in the resulting dictionary.

Comment: What function? You haven't created a function - if you did then you could reuse it for any object.

Comment: @ Martijin Peters the code is to big to post but i need return each object attributes alone according to user input if i pass the other objects to vars it will just print all attributes of all objects isn't there a variable that i can replace the Animal object with so it returns the one the user specifies

Comment: @ AChampion yes i created function i'll update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out all i had to do was assigning user input to a variable then call it from objects like this :

```
class Animal(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.legs = 2
          self.name = 'Dog'
          self.color= 'Spotted'
          self.smell= 'Alot'
          self.age  = 10
          self.kids = 0

 noun = input()
 def get_info(noun) :
     if __name__ == '__main__':
        character = Object.objects[noun]
        temp = vars(character)
        for item in temp:
            print(item , ' : ' , temp[item])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the variable you should do this:

```
class Animal(object):
      def __init__(self, legs, name, color, smell, age, kids):
          self.legs = legs
          self.name = name
          self.color= color
          self.smell= smell
          self.age  = age
          self.kids = kids

if __name__ == '__main__':
    animal = Animal(2, 'Dog', 'Spotted', 'Alot', 10, 0)
    temp = vars(animal)
    for item in temp:
        print(item , ' : ' , temp[item])
```

Comment: i still have to write a function for each object this way

Comment: So explain to me exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: i am trying to define a function that returns all attributes of an object , so when a user wants to know about the object all he has to is activate that function for the object he specifies out of multiple objects.